# Automatically setting permissions on files created in a directory

Tags: linux, file, permissions, directory

I would like to have a directory in my Linux machine with 777 permissions, however anyfile placed (copied/moved) inside will need to automatically have 666 permission set.
In other words, is it possible in Linux to have a directory where any files placed side automatically becomes un-executable?

Comment: Is it more important that it be 666, or that files in that directory not be executable?

Answer (score 1):

You can mount a filesystem with the `noexec` flag; any file within such a system will not be executable even if its permissions indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

A good way of doing this would be to use the "umask" builtin, this affects the file creation mask for the current shell environment, you can get the current mask with

```
umask -S
```

So to create files with a certain mask, you could do the following :

```
mask_for_file_creation="u=rw,g=rw,o=rw"
curr_mask=$(umask -S)
umask $mask_for_file_creation
#create files here
umask $curr_mask
```

providing the mask as the first argument to umask sets the mask to that value.